# Got this error after refreshing page in ReactJS app: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router-dom

I keep getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'` after I refresh the page. The error comes from a top level component called `<Navbar />` which I added in App.js. The issue is not present in any other component and there is also no error when I navigate to the page from another page. **Only when I refresh the page**

I think it assumes the the html page `index.html` in the public folder is a js file.

[image]

How do I fix this any why does it only occur on certain pages.

Pages that work well:

```
<Route path="/" element={<div><br /> <br /> Hello</div>} />
<Route path="/newcollection" element={<NewCollection />} />
```

Pages that don't work well:

```
<Route path="/:contractAddress/:metaDataHash/:ownerAddress/mint" element={<NewNFT />} />
```

More relevant info:

[image]

I have a strong feeling that it has to do with the way I imported JS here. As shown in the error message.
[image]

Comment: try to reorder the routes

Comment: Can you include [all relevant code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) you've an issue working with? Seems you need to configure your server to bounce page requests to your root index.html file so the routing can work. Where is your app deployed to and running?

Comment: I am working on my locallhost. I honestly have no idea what triggered it. And it will be difficult to post all relevant code here. I will try to add more relevant info as images @DrewReese .

Comment: It seems that you are using jQuery before it is loaded.

Comment: @LajosArpad I think so .

Comment: Move all the `script` tags *above` `<div id="root" />` where your React app is being rendered.

Comment: @DrewReese I did, it didn't work. I think it might be affected by react-router-dom's `path="/:contractAddress/:metaDataHash/:ownerAddress/`

Comment: The only page affected is the one with the variable url `/:contractAddress/:metaDataHash/:ownerAddress/`

Comment: Check the jquery and other files are loaded in proper sequence.

Comment: I did a little experiment. Summary is wrote a random url : `http://localhost:3000/newcollection/yvuvin`.  It triggered the same error. I think it has to do with react recognizing the route or something

Comment: How are you building and running your app? It's an issue with accessing sub-routes, the server is trying to serve up a page from that directory but it doesn't exist.

Comment: @DrewReese, I think it's related to routing but the route was defined in App.js as shown the only difference is that is a variable route.

Comment: Having route params isn't the issue, it's any sub-route, like I said and like you tested, and the server is trying to serve a file that doesn't exist. How are you running the code locally?

Comment: @DrewReese it's a react app. I am using npm `(npm start)` to run it.  @DrewReese. I just got a light bulb moment. And I think this might just work. I will answer the question

Answer (score 3):

I was able to arrive to this answer thanks to the comments especially @DrewReese.

The issue was with how I located the js and css files in the `index.html` page. For some reason react was able to locate the files with out `/` prepend to source location. SO, I basically solved all the problems by adding `/`
ahead of all source in the index.html folder.
And now it looks like this:

```
<script src="/js/modernizr-3.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

instead of this:

```
<script src="js/modernizr-3.8.0.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery is required by some libraries, you would do well to move the `script` tag with the `src` of jQuery above all other `script` tags. modernizr is above jQuery in your image. If the issue still reproduces, then click on the error in your dev tools and see which line is throwing it and which file the line is located at. Make sure that before that file is loaded, jQuery is already loaded.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have written the,
"homepage": "."
in my package.json file. After removing it the error was resolved.